# Inconsistent DateObjects in Range stepped by Month

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

A number of inconsistencies using `Range` with `DateObject` when they are stepped through using (time) `Quantity`.

This Q relates to Range, Quantity and DateObjects, as `DateRange` syntax and options are not as readable and further functionalities that are supposed to be interoperable (otherwise, why does Range support DateObject at all?)

```
Range[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}],Quantity[1, "Month"]]
```

[image]

where's Jul 1? It's included by moving `Range` start point to Mar 1:

```
Range[DateObject[{2016, 3, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}], 
 Quantity[1, "Month"]]
```

[image]

Similarly for end-of-month, one would hope `Quantity[1,"Month"] is consistent with the mixed-base calendars rather than just adding 30 days:

```
Range[DateObject[{2016, 3, 31}], DateObject[{2016, 6, 30}], 
 Quantity[1, "Month"]]
```

[image]

Where's Jun 30? Again, can be seen by moving starting point, here to Apr 30 but returns May 30, rather than May 31

```
Range[DateObject[{2016, 4, 30}], DateObject[{2016, 6, 30}], 
 Quantity[1, "Month"]]
```

[image]

Even if the correct end-of-months (except for, again, missing endpoint) is obtained from certain starting points, eg

```
Range[DateObject[{2015, 12, 31}], DateObject[{2016, 6, 30}], 
 Quantity[1, "Month"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `DateRange` is more appropriate here.

Comment: @swish, I'm aware of DateRange, but its syntax and options are not as readable. In any case this Q regards Range and Quantity. Wolfram has built a set of functionalities that are supposed to be interoperable.

Comment: @alancalvitti Can you explain how `DateRange[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}], "Month"]` is not as readable as `Range[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}], 
 Quantity[1, "Month"]]`?  Not only are the parameters near identical but you can make them identical by using `Quantity[1, "Month"]` in `DateRange`.  It is the exact same parameter list; with the added benefit that `DateRange` returns the expected list of dates.

Comment: @Edmund, a colleague had provided me an example using `DateRange` with more parameters. I should reword to say "less orthogonal" rather than less readable, in that if `Range` worked as intended, `DateRange` - a more restricted function - could be deprecated.

Comment: @alancalvitti I would say that `Range` does work as intended and so does `DateRange`.

Comment: @Edmund, I don't think so, the concept of a month is understood to be a mixed base quantity, not a flat 365/12 average, if you have time please review the inconsistencies identified in my examples, as I indicated to WReach as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Summary**

`Range` applied to non-integers can be reduced to an expression involving an integral range -- i.e. `Range[min, max, di]` is notionally equivalent to

```
min + di * Range[0, Floor[(max - min) / di]]
```

A problem arises when the `min` and `max` are dates and `di` is a duration.  In `min + di * ...`, the duration `di * ...` is evaluated from the base date `min` and entails exact month lengths.  On the contrary, `(max - min) / di` resolves to a ratio of two durations with no base date for reference.  In this case, `di` is interpreted using a "generic" month length of 365/12 days.  It is the mismatch of these two interpretations of `di` that gives rise to an unexpected number of entries in the result.

Furthermore, when a duration of *n* months is added to a date, the computation attempts to preserve the day number of the initial date if possible.  This is why the generated dates do not always fall at month-end even though the initial date does.

**Work-around**

`DateRange` operates upon dates as dates-proper (as [@swish](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2490/swish) notes in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149061/inconsistent-dateobjects-in-range-stepped-by-month#comment400086_149061)).  It respects actual month lengths instead of generic ones and will produce the expected results:

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}], "Month"]

(* DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], ..., DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}] *)
```

It can also pin the generated dates to month-end, if desired:

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2015, 12, 31}], DateObject[{2016, 6, 30}], "EndOfMonth"]

(* {DateObject[{2015, 12, 31}], ..., DateObject[{2016, 5, 31}], ...} *)
```

**Analysis**

A trace of the original expression is very lengthy, but we can inspect certain substeps to see what is going on:

[image: trace screenshot]

We can see a subexpression which is performing the interval division `(max - min) / di`, which ultimately resolves to:

```
Quantity[151, "Day"] * Quantity[1, Power["Months", -1]]

(* 1812 / 365 *)
```

Simple arithmetic operations like this can be applied to date objects, but it entails a conversion to a common unit.  The trace does not reveal the choice made by *Mathematica*, but all choices lead to the same result:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[151, "Day"], #]& /@ {"Days", "Months", "Years"}

(* {Quantity[151, "Days"], Quantity[1812/365, "Months"], Quantity[151/365, "Years"]} *)

UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Month"], #]& /@ {"Days", "Months", "Years"}

(* {Quantity[365/12, "Days"], Quantity[1, "Months"], Quantity[1/12, "Years"]} *)

% / %%

(* {365/1812, 365/1812, 365/1812} *)
```

So when *Mathematica* attempts to convert these interval sizes into a common unit, it is using a generic duration for a month, i.e. 365/12 days.  It is this generic month length that ultimately causes the behaviour under discussion.

The floor of this interval division value is 4, and indeed the trace contains another subexpression which is generating a list of five dates (i.e. initial value plus four more), namely:

```
{ DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}]
, DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}] + Quantity[1, "Month"]
, DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}] + 2 * Quantity[1, "Month"]
, DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}] + 3 * Quantity[1, "Month"]
, DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}] + 4 * Quantity[1, "Month"]
}
```

[image: date list]

Once again, the trace shows evidence that a generic algorithm is being used to create the range.

Now that we have seen how `Range` generates its result, we should be able to get a list with six entries just by adding enough days to the interval so that the floor-plus-one is six instead of five:

```
{##, #2 - #1, N[(#2 - #1) / Quantity[1, "Month"]]}&[
  DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, #}]]& /@
 {1, 2, 3} // Grid
```

[image: interval list]

The rollover point is July 3:

```
Range[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 2}], Quantity[1, "Months"]]

(* {DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], ..., DateObject[{2016, 6, 1}] *)

Range[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 3}], Quantity[1, "Months"]]

(* {DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], ..., DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}] *)
```

`DateRange` does not suffer from these problems because it uses an algorithm that is specifically designed to work upon (and only upon) date objects:

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 2}], Quantity[1, "Months"]]

(* {DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], ..., DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}] *)

DateRange[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 3}], Quantity[1, "Months"]]

(* {DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], ..., DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}] *)

DateRange[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 7, 31}], Quantity[1, "Months"]]

(* {DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], ..., DateObject[{2016, 7, 1}] *)

DateRange[DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 8, 1}], Quantity[1, "Months"]]

(* {DateObject[{2016, 2, 1}], ..., DateObject[{2016, 8, 1}] *)
```

**Month Ends**

The final two expressions in the question show that adding a duration of one or more months to a month-end date does not always yield a month-end result.  More directly:

```
DateObject[{2015, 3, 31}] + Quantity[2, "Months"]

(* DateObject[{2015, 5, 31}] *)
```

yet:

```
DateObject[{2015, 4, 30}] + Quantity[1, "Months"]

(* DateObject[{2015, 5, 30}] *)
```

In fact, such additions attempt to preserve the day number of the initial date, only changing it if the day does not exist in the month:

```
DateObject[{2015, 9, 30}] + Quantity[1, "Month"] * Range[0, 11]
```

[image: dates]

Notice how all dates fall on the 30th, except for February which only has 29 days.

`DateRange` can be used to force all dates to lie at month-end:

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2015, 9, 30}], DateObject[{2016, 8, 31}], "EndOfMonth"]
```

[image: dates]

**Design Choice?**

This behaviour appears to be a design choice made by WRI.  Had `Range` been written to use exact date arithmetic instead of generic period sizes, there would be no need for `DateRange` to exist.  But this would also mean that we would lose the ability, for example, to expressly choose between preserving the day number or pinning to month-end when adding durations to dates.

The `Range` documentation is virtually silent about being able to operate upon dates.  It states that "*the arguments to Range need not be integers*" and an example shows that `Quantity` objects are acceptable.  It may very well be that the ability to apply `Range` to dates is merely a side-effect of its ability to operate upon `Quantity` objects.  The design consequences in the context of dates might not have been explicitly considered.

Comment: Does "It is because of this generic length (365/12 days) that we see the results that are obtained" explain my last example? `Range[DateObject[{2015, 12, 31}], DateObject[{2016, 6, 30}], 
 Quantity[1, "Month"]]`

Comment: @alancalvitti No.  The differing behaviour between your last two examples is due to the date arithmetic expression mentioned in the main body of the response.  Specifically, adding months using expressions of the form `date + n * Quantity[1, "Months"]` will preserve the day number as far as possible.  To force the calculation use of month-ends, we need to resort to `DatePlus` or `DateRange` using `"EndOfMonth"` as the unit.  Later I will update my response to mention this explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

If you must use [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html) with [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) instead of [`DateRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateRange.html) I suggest using dates that are of the same granularity as the `Range` increment.

`DateObject[{yyyy, mm}]` will give a `DateObject` of *month* granularity.  You can also specify the granularity with the second parameter; `DateObject[{yyyy, mm}, "Month"]`.

```
dates = Range[DateObject[{2016, 2}], DateObject[{2016, 7}], Quantity[1, "Month"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Once you have your range of months you can adjust them with the [Date & Time](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DateAndTime.html) functions.

```
DatePlus[dates, "EndOfMonth"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Edmund, increments and granularity are dictated by business needs, not by what's convenient. By the way, can get the same answer as above by doing Range on 1st of month, and then subtracting `Quantity[1,"Days"]`.

Comment: @alancalvitti You can also set complete dates to monthly granularity, `DateObject[{2016,2,1},"Month"]`. I am just detailing how you need to use `Range` with `DateObject`s.  If you must do it than the about method will work.

Comment: in revising this (11.3), `DatePlus[dates, "EndOfMonth"]` is not returning the last date of the month, but rather seems to leave the input dates invariant. Can you replicate?

Answer (score 2):

Just gonna share my thoughts on the implementation of `Range`. I've came up with two naive ways to define it:

```
range1[from_, to_, step_] := Most@NestWhileList[# + step &, from, # <= to &]
range2[from_, to_, step_] := NestList[# + step &, from, Floor[(to - from)/step]]
```

And it seems the real `Range` works more like `range2`, and `DateRange` like `range1`. As the date difference returns number of days, the rounding in `range2` pretty much explains its behaviour.